# Revert Anaconda like the first time installed

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have two environments created in `Users/user/conda/envs` which I don't need anymore. I saw that there is also `pkgs` in `Users/user/conda` and both of them `Users/user/conda/envs` and `Users/user/conda/pkgs` really eat a lot lot lot of my storage. I want to delete those two environment.

1. Does `conda remove -n env_name --all` delete the environment and all its installed packages under its environment too? Or does it only delete the environment?
2. Can I delete directly folder `pkgs` and `env` from `Users/user` without affect the **base** environment?
3. How can one revert Anaconda like the first time installed (contain only **base** environment and the default packages)?

Or do I need uninstall Anaconda and re-install it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Specific Answers

> 1. Does `conda remove -n env_name --all` delete the environment and all its installed packages under its environment too? Or does it only delete the environment?

It will delete environment **my_env**, which includes the unpacked libraries and the `env/env_name` directory. It will not delete the cached tarballs in the `conda/pkgs` directory.

> 2. Can I delete directly folder `pkgs` and `env` from Users/user without affect the base environment?

**Yes.** However, be aware that if softlinks (symbolic linking) are being used, deleting the `pkgs` directory could break environments. One can check whether softlinks are enabled with

```bash
conda config --show allow_softlinks always_softlink
```

though this cannot tell if any are in use.

Also, Conda packages can include `pre-unlink` scripts, which may contain code expect to be evaluated during the package removal process. Deleting the environment directly would ignore such protocols and could lead to empty references.

Generally, I would recommend using the commands available in the CLI, rather than deleting folders. If you wish to delete an environment, you should use the command in **(1)**.  If you wish to delete cached packages, you should use `conda clean` (use `--help` flag to see the options available).

> 3. How can one revert Anaconda like the first time installed (contain only **base** environment and the default packages)?

Again, you can delete the other envs with `conda remove --all`. For **base**, you can revert it to the original state with

```
conda install -n base --revision 0
```

However, I will note that many users report this not working or at least have problems if they revert too far back. Instead, look back at the history of revisions with `conda list --revisions` and pick a state that removes what you don't want.

## General Recommendation

#### Miniforge

Since you seem like you want a clean break, I'd recommend the complete uninstall of Anaconda. However, since you appear primarily concerned with space, instead of reinstalling Anaconda, consider switching to [a Miniforge variant](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge), which only includes the Conda package manager and minimal infrastructure to support it. Then create environments that only include the packages that you actually require. You can still use `conda clean --tarballs` to minimize cached downloads, but already with Miniforge you should have a significantly smaller footprint than the full Anaconda distribution.

#### Managing Environments

As a general rule of thumb, I recommend using **base** only for installing Conda infrastructure (e.g., `conda`, `mamba`, `conda-build`, `boa`) and using separate environments for the specific package environments you need (e.g., TensorFlow, PyTorch). In my experience, this helps to keep your **base** more stable, and allows you to partition off potential package conflicts and wrap up specific projects by clearing out environments after you no longer need them.

Comment: Oh great answer as it is what I need. With conda clean -tp, we can also delete the tarballs and unused packages right? Thank you so much for your brief answer!

Comment: @RezaHabibi yes, but do note the cautionary message in the help text. I didn't want to put that directly in the answer because I try to avoid posting commands that could be problematic if simply copy and pasted. I will say that on my previous laptop that I had Anaconda on for a couple years, I ran that occasionally without issue.